# Import Excel file to MySQL using PHP Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, excel, import, yii2-advanced-app

I just want to import data from excel (xls, xlsx) to mySql db in Yii2 using PHPExcel.
This is my code in Controller:

```
$modelFile ->file = $firstName. '_' .$middleName. '_' .date('Y-m-d'). '_' .$file ->getBaseName(). "." .$file ->getExtension();
$objPHPExcel = new \PHPExcel();
$inputFiles = fopen("../file/".$modelFile ->file, "r");

try {
  $inputFileType = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFiles);
  $objReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
  $objPHPExcel = $objReader ->load($inputFiles);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  die('Error');
}

$sheet = $objPHPExcel ->getSheet(0);
$highestRow = $sheet ->getHighestRow();
$highestColumn = $sheet ->getHighestColumn();

//$row is start 2 because first row assigned for heading.         
for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {

  $rowData = $sheet ->rangeToArray('A'.$row. ':' .$highestColumn.$row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);

  //save to branch table.
  $modelHeader = new FakturOut();
  $modelDetail = new FakturOutDetail();

  $modelHeader ->name = $rowData[0][0];
  $modelHeader ->age = $rowData[0][1];
  $modelHeader ->address = $rowData[0][2];
  $modelHeader ->academic_id = $rowData[0][3];
  $modelHeader ->mother_name = $rowData[0][4];
  $modelHeader ->father_Name = $rowData[0][5];
  $modelHeader ->gender = $rowData[0][6];
  $modelHeader ->height = $rowData[0][7];
  $modelHeader ->weight= $rowData[0][8];
  $modelHeader ->save();
}
```

And then the browser return an error notification like **pathinfo() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given**. Please help to solve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code you have used

```
 $inputFileType =\PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFiles);
```

which is used to identify the valid excel file and it expects the parameter as `filename`.

I can see in your code, you have passed `$inputFiles` as a parameter to  `identify` method, which is not a file name but resource handler. and `identify` method expects it to be string (file name).

This is the reason you are getting error.

**Note : fopen() returns a file pointer resource on success, or FALSE on error.**

```
    $inputFiles = fopen("../file/" . $modelFile->file, "r");
```

Comment: Yah, the error has been solved. I just follow your instruction.
I just add new line code like this `$fileName = "../file/" . $newTempModel->file;`. Thankyou somuch